# Using Floggy on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Does anyone use Floggy API on a BlackBerry development? I'm looking for something like SQLite (which is supported on JDE 5.0, but I am using 4.6).

Comment: Do you want to know how to use Floggy, or you want to know the alternative to SQLite?

Comment: Both will be helpfull. I've found floggy but I can change if there is something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. We had some discussion about this a time ago. Search at the archives http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=floggy-user